# Having an issue with the header text and its alignment

Tags: html, css, header, alignment, center

When I run my website on a browser, the header (Some Header) should be centered at the top of the webpage but its centered in the middle of webpage. I need some help of fixing this but still keeping the header in a fixed position.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Some Title</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="Logo.png" type="img/SVG" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
</head>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        background-image: url("Road.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;

    }
    .header {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height:70px;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-align:right;
    }
    .socialmedia {
        position:fixed;
        right:150px;
        top:35px;
        transform:translate(0,-50%);
        display: flex; /* add this */
        align-items: center; /* add this */
    }

    .footer {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90px;
        margin-top: 319px;
    }
</style>

<body>
<div class="Coming Soon" style=" color: black;">
    <div class="header">
    <a href="website"><h1 style = "text-align: center; font-family: Verdana; font-size: x-large; font-style: italic">Some Header</h1></a>

    <style>
        a{text-decoration: none;
            color: white; }
    </style>
    <div class="socialmedia">
        <img src="Logo.png" style=" width: 130px; height: 80px; margin-right: 100px">
        <a class="Facebook">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/09/facebook-icon-preview-1.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class="Instagram">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/Instagram-logo.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>
        <a class="Youtube">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/YouTube-icon.png" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
        </a>

    </div>
    </div>
    <p style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: x-large; text-align: center; margin-top: 300px">Some Paragraph</p>
    <div class="footer" style=" color: black;">

        <p style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: small; padding-left: 55%;">2017 Some Company | City State Website All Right Reserved.</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add `top:0;` to `.header`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Comment: @NoahTanenholtz perhaps, but it's using absolute positioning and it's not recommended practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html5 has a native tag `header`, you don't need to define it as a class, but that's an aside.

If you amend your position to relative (recommended), and moreover, remove the `text-align:right;` , your 'Some Header' will most likely appear as you want it to.

A note: you have a lot of inline style in your html (and excess html - too many a tags - you have link tags within links unnecessarily - you can remove some). I would recommend you put the inline css in with the css (preferably in a css stylesheet) rather than in the html document. If necessary, you can add a class if you wish to use the same tag later with a variation.

Hope this helps

Comment: For the purposes of making the header obvious, I changed the link 'a' style from white to red. This is how your html would look with html5 tags and  decluttered html https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/1tcpggst/